# How can I manipulate my Drupal blogs?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, blogs, cms-migration

I'm migrating a website from FrogCMS to Drupal. My questions are:

- How do you limit the list of recent blog entries (title and content) on the MAIN page and let it limit (to at least five) on the other page (i.e. List of Blogs page)?
- How do you place a 'read more' link for each blog and when viewed full, the 'read more' should not be displayed?
- Is there a way to remove the pagination without hacking node.module?
- I tried Nodequeue module but I am not sure on how to use it. I read the documentation and tried outputing `<?php print nodequeue_node_titles($subqueue_id); ?>` but had no luck at all. [Check it here](http://drupal.org/node/293117)
- I need an answer ASAP. I need to finish this by tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check out Views module. This will allow you to build the views you require. If you want to further modify the output then do this then theme the view.

There is a tutorial for nodequeue here [link text](http://www.drupal.org.uk/node/257) which may help you.

Comment: Oh thanks! It took me awhile to understand the Views module but finally I did it! Thanks!!